# How to prove $f:(X,\mathcal T_{X}) \rightarrow (Y,\mathcal T_{Y})$ is continuous iff for all $U$ in the basis of $Y$, $f^{-1}(U) \in\mathcal T_{X}$

Tags: general-topology

> How to prove a map $f:(X,\mathcal T_{X}) \rightarrow (Y,\mathcal
>  T_{Y})$ of topological spaces is continuous iff for all $U$ in the
>    basis of $Y$, $f^{-1}(U) \in\mathcal T_{X}$

I have no problem with the forwards statement but there's something I don't understand about the proof of the reverse statement

Here's my professor's proof:

1. Let $\mathcal B$ be a basis for $\mathcal T_Y$ and suppose $U\in\mathcal B \Rightarrow f^{-1}(U) \in\mathcal T_{X}$
2. Let $W\in \mathcal T_Y$ be an arbitrary set
3. There exists $(U_i)\in \mathcal B$ s.t. $W = \bigcup_{i\in I} U_i$
4. $f^{-1}(W) = f^{-1}(\bigcup_{i\in I} U_i) = \bigcup_{i\in I} f^{-1}(U_i)$
5. Any union of open sets $f^{-1}(U_i)$ is open therefore $f^{-1}(W)$ is open
6. Therefore $f$ is continuous

Why is it that in step 4. the $f^{-1}$ can be moved inside the union? Is it some property of a topological space that I am forgetting?

Comment: It is basic property of pre-image of a function. It behaves well with unions and intersections

Comment: More precisely
$$f^{-1} \left (  \bigcup _{\alpha\in I} Y_\alpha \right ) = \bigcup _{\alpha\in I} f^{-1}(Y_\alpha) $$
same for arbitrary intersections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s a property of inverse functions.

If $x\in f^{-1}\left(\bigcup_i U_i \right)$, then  $f(x)\in \bigcup_iU_i$ and so $f(x)\in U_i$ for some $i$. Thus $x\in f^{-1}(U_i)$ for some $i$, so $x\in\bigcup_i f^{-1}(U_i)$.

These steps are reversible, so we have equality of
$f^{-1}\left(\bigcup_i U_i \right)$ and $\bigcup_i f^{-1}(U_i)$.

---

A basic piece of advice is that if you’re trying to show two sets are equal, try showing a point that is in one set must also be in the other set, and vice versa.